# Magento 1.9.2.4 "admin/system_config" admin page throws errors after migrate from 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, magento-1, system-config, ce-1.9.2.4

*System -> configuration* admin page on Magento (1.9.2.4) throwing below errors after I get migrated from (1.7.0.2).

```
a:5:{i:0;s:51:"Controller file was loaded but class does not exist";i:1;s:1209:"
#0 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(340): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Controller file...')
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(308): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->_includeControllerClass('/data/16/3/97/9...', 'Mage_Adminhtml_...')
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(196): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->_validateControllerClassName('Mage_Adminhtml', 'system_config')
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
{main}";s:3:"url";s:31:"/index.php/admin/system_config/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you remove the compilation before upgrading and clear cache ?

If yes, the most probable case is that you have a controler that is not declared properly.

You can check which module is guilty by unactivating them one by one.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Actually am new for magento, i haven't remove the compilation before upgrading and cleared cache. Can you please let me know how can i check by disable the modules based on my above errors ?

Comment: https://kb.magenting.com/content/24/81/en/disable-magento-compiler.html this link must help you